# Laravel-sail & docker file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I configured my project to work with WSL 2, on ubuntu 22.0. And it works perfectly, however now I need to configure the project on a linux server.

The phpmyadmin and mysql are working!

The error when I do: docker-compose up

[image: logs]

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: rsu-8.1/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-8080}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            #- redis
            #- selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
        networks: 
            - sail
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    #redis:
    #     image: 'redis:alpine'
    #     ports:
    #         - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
    #     volumes:
    #         - 'sailredis:/data'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    #     healthcheck:
    #       test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    #meilisearch:
    #     image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
    #     ports:
    #         - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
    #     volumes:
    #         - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    #
    #mailhog:
    #    image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
    #    ports:
    #        - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
    #        - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
    #    networks:
    #        - sail
    #selenium:
    #    image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    #    volumes:
    #         - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    #    networks:
    #        - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    #sailredis:
    #    driver: local
    #sailmeilisearch:
    #    driver: local
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:+6ss7B4aED3QCVCSUTAFAG/+NslL8GQYG8BwuTjUyEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://rsu-new-app.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=Messages
DB_USERNAME=fabio
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached

SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=localhost"

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700

JWT_SECRET=qQqAfUyZcaPanHXkj0YpHC9OfooeOiuVDSXygghugzwAYen0DJyUHaG1RdxXEzMj

WWWGROUP=1002
WWWUSER=1002
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=14

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && gpg --recv-key 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c \
    && gpg --export 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c > /usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev \
       php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd \
       php8.1-curl \
       php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring \
       php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap \
       php8.1-intl php8.1-readline \
       php8.1-ldap \
       php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole \
       php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

Im using 1002 for user and group because is my user
[image]

So far I've tried:

- Swap the created user 'sail' for my 'crashmaster', changing the dockerfile files;
- I've also changed the rsu volume in the .env file to this:
  volumes:
  - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro
  - /etc/group:/etc/group:ro

I have no more ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got a approach for u

```
# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
```

used instead of

```
RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail
```

also WWWUSER and WWWGROUP can always stay on 1000 the code from above is from a small production application so i confirmed it works like that

that would be a different Approach and not suggested since it works
like chmod 777

```
sudo chmod o+w ./storage/ -R
```

you can also check if it is linked

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: I replaced the code in the docker file, I changed the code again to 1000 in the .env file and got the error "sail does not exist", so I changed the start-container file and the supervisord.conf file for the new www user.
With this I got the same error, lack of permissions.
Interesting that running "sudo chmod o+w ./storage/ -R" doesn't solve the problem either
Would you like to see anything else?

Comment: Container logs
[link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e6dd27682a017de5cecdb0d1294a567720221129210908/28017c)

Comment: are you sure your dockerfile was in the right path when u run the chmod? (and dont use sudo in Dockerfile sorry that i wrote that in usually docker images dont have sudo)

Comment: @FábioBaptista i really hope its the a failure with the path.. all our projects use     volumes:
      - "./:/var/www" instead of /var/www/html so might be that the chown gets executed in the wrong path.  I cant anything else thats off... path is the only option i can see

Comment: @FábioBaptista well theres more. Friend just told me u should use chmod -R 775 storage outside of the container on the real path. so the local path in your system. it seems that it can belong to your user on the pc . we shouldve cleard that problem with the sudo chmod... but if that doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, running the chmod command without sudo worked for the problem I had

Answer (score 0):

i had solve this problem just with this code :

```
sail artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Try to include an explanation of how your answer solves the problem, it helps people learn why the problem occured in the first place!